# How to set a image pattern and color gradients as background

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I see modern sites putting a color gradient + pattern as the page background.
You may take a look at the 'jumbotron' class of twitter bootstrap site  [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html).

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4), 0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    background: #020031;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%, #6d3353 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#020031), color-stop(100%,#6d3353));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #020031 0%,#6d3353 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#020031', endColorstr='#6d3353',GradientType=1 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), inset 0 -3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.jumbotron::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative; /* changed by me */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/bs-docs-masthead-pattern.png) repeat center center;
    opacity: .4;
}
```

What I need is to create, say 10 classes like above each pointing to different image patterns. I should be able to use these CSS classes to give 10 different patterns to each of the thumbnails in the gallery.

When I set the jumbotron class to any of the thumbnail, it stretches out the whole page.

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set a `width` and a `height`:

```
.jumbotron {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    /* the rest of your CSS properties */
}
```

Also, don't forget about adjusting the `padding` as needed.

Comment: Thank you mathew.. Let me try your solution

Comment: it didnt work. is that the problem with background - cover property ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the code that isn't working? What are you seeing?